# Spring Roo 2 deployment

Tags: spring-roo

After following the instructions web Roo site:

```
mkdir hello
cd hello
roo.sh
roo> project setup --topLevelPackage com.foo
roo> jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
roo> entity jpa --class ~.domain.Timer
roo> field string --fieldName message --notNull
roo> repository jpa --all
roo> service --all
roo> web mvc setup
roo> web mvc view setup --type THYMELEAF
roo> web mvc controller --all --responseType THYMELEAF
roo> web mvc controller --all --pathPrefix /api
roo> quit
```

I run

```
mvn package
```

as described in Roo reference (https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/#using-spring-roo-create-boot-app)

As a result of this action there are two jars created.

```
target/foo-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
target/foo-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar
```

Instructions says to run it with command

```
java -jar target/foo-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And this all goes well. But after clicking on list item on the web page I get an exception.

```
2017-10-05 14:48:43.940 ERROR 1514 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template "timers/list": Error resolving fragment: "${content}": template or fragment could not be resolved (template: "fragments/modal-confirm-delete" - line 18, col 16)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving fragment: "${content}": template or fragment could not be resolved (template: "fragments/modal-confirm-delete" - line 18, col 16)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor.java:116) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1304) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.0.RELEASE]
```

NOTE: this does not occur in case app is run using

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all your steps were correct. This is a minor issue of spring-roo-2.0.0.RC2.

I have a suggestion in the [Spring JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3944?focusedCommentId=156307&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-156307)